# My dns works when I do a "dig @mynameserver hostname" but not when I do a "dig hostname"

Tags: dns, whois, nameservers

My nameserver isn't working properly, and I can't figure out why.

When I do a 'whois cfconsulting.ca', it shows the correct nameservers, with ns1.signupsystems.com being the primary. If you do a "dig @ns1.signupsystems.com cfconsulting.ca" you get the right IP.

But if you just do an 'nslookup cfconsulting.ca' it fails.

I'm baffled.

Comment: You might have better luck asking your question on ServerFault.com. We're more into programming questions here.

Comment: You're right - I would much rather have asked in a more appropriate forum -- but I'd never heard of serverfault.com, and I had seen dns questions asked here, so I went ahead and asked even though I knew it was a bit of a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the appropriate server in /etc/resolv.conf if you're using a UNIX (as opposed to a Windows) system.  There are numerous ports of Dig to Windows; if using Windows please RTFM (or, if needed, UTSL) to see how they get their default servers.

Comment: Actually, the issue was with my domain's CNAME records for its dns servers, and has since been resolved.

But thanks for your reply anyway. ;)

Comment: Glad things are working.  If you don't mind a shameless plug, you may want to look at my DNS server MaraDNS (as well as looking at PowerDNS and Unbound, two other excellent open-source DNS servers).  There's more to DNS than BIND and DjbDNS.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to read the report:

http://www.dnsvalidation.com/reports/4d2458e07d79ee0c8b00000a

Your secondary nameserver (*ns2.signupsystems.com*) is not responding to DNS queries regarding domain *cfconsulting.ca*, it may be a nameserver misconfiguration (check zone configuration and ACLs) or a firewall issue (allow UDP packets to port 53) :

```
[vitalie@silver ~]$ dig @ns2.signupsystems.com cfconsulting.ca

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-4.P1.el5_5.3 <<>> @ns2.signupsystems.com cfconsulting.ca
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Nameserver seems to be online, *ns2.signupsystems.com* is responding to ping requests:

```
[vitalie@silver ~]$ ping -c 3 ns2.signupsystems.com
PING ns2.signupsystems.com (69.31.163.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 69.31.163.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=222 ms
64 bytes from 69.31.163.69: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=218 ms
64 bytes from 69.31.163.69: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=212 ms

--- ns2.signupsystems.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 212.463/217.812/222.049/4.028 ms
```